# Cant run python project because of version issue

Tags: python

I am trying to install twint project but when i try it with pip it says `ERROR: Package 'twint' requires a different Python: 2.7.16 not in '>=3.5.0'` and when i try with

```
pip3 install twint
```

It says `ERROR: Package 'twint' requires a different Python: 2.7.16 not in '>=3.5.0'`. It would be great if you guys show me the right way to install it.

[screen shot of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWTGC.png)

Comment: You have to install python3 in your machine [How to Install python 3 on mac](https://programwithus.com/learn-to-code/install-python3-mac/)

Comment: Just to be sure - what is the output of 'pip --version' and 'pip3 --version' ?

Comment: Also, based on "normal site-packages not writable", maybe you need 'sudo pip install twint' instead.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, both your `pip3` and `pip` use Python 2.7.

You'll have to unfudge your Python installation(s) so that doesn't happen to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

The python version is set to 2.7 in the Pipfile:

```
[requires]
python_version = "2.7"
```

Needs to be set to at least 3.5 or whatever is installed on your system as required by the twint package.